# Why StAX classes were not retrofitted for ARM in Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, stax, try-with-resources

I expected to find `XMLStreamReader` to be `AutoCloseable` in Java 7. However, that is not the case. Is there a technical reason why StAX reader/writer interfaces were not (or should not be) retrofitted to implement `AutoCloseable` ?  They already have close methods, whose intent is not different from the close method of `AutoCloseable`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look closer to the [`close()` method of `AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close%28%29) :

> Closes this resource, relinquishing any underlying resources. This method is invoked automatically on objects managed by the try-with-resources statement.

Or even [`Closeable` `close()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close%28%29) :

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it. If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

Whereas the [`close()` method of `XMLStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#close%28%29) says :

> Frees any resources associated with this Reader. **This method does not close the underlying input source.**

Indeed the input source is managed by the [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) which implement the `Closeable` interface. So it's the reader that can be close in the *try-with-ressource*.

For example :

```
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader reader = null;
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.xml")) { //Will close the FileReader
        reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(fr);
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
        if(reader!=null)try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (XMLStreamException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would personally restructure that code. reader.close() should be in a finally block in case an exception occurs (your catch is only for XMLStreamException but it could throw an unchecked exception too.) I would also remove the check for reader being null and simply nest a second level of try-finally inside the other try block.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason why they couldn't have made these things `AutoCloseable`. I figure it just comes down to laziness or insufficient time looking for methods called close().